# JavaScript Vector Function

Tags: javascript, vector

Does anyone know if there is supposed to be a PI in a simple vector function that takes these values and spits out a new x/y?

Will this work for all vector calculations in a browser situation?

c is a coordinate array [x,y]

a is the angle in degrees

d is the distance

```js
var vec = function(c,a,d){
nx = c[0] + (Math.cos(a)*d)
ny = c[1] + (Math.sin(a)*d)
return [nx,ny]
}

console.log(vec([10,10],45,50))
```

Comment: If `a` is in degrees then it won't work. If it is in radians then it will work. PI is required to convert between degrees and radians but most programmers who are used to calculating angles don't bother. They just get used to the idea that 2PI is one circle.

Comment: So yeah my question is 'Do I need to convert Degrees in Sin/Cos functions in javascript by adding the PI 180 thing?

You just re-worded my question without answering.

Comment: If you read carefully, my comment provided the answer: **that 2PI is one circle**. Form that one should be able to figure out how to convert degrees to radians if one knows how many degrees there are in one circle.

Comment: If you answered the question you would of said something like;

If you are using degrees you will have to convert them to radians by multiplying your degrees by Math.PI/180.

You just provided loads of sarcasm only a math guy would understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**. From the documentation for [Math.cos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos) and [Math.sin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin):

> `Math.cos(x)` ... `x` - A number given in unit of **radians**.
>   `Math.sin(x)` ... `x` - A number (given in **radians**).

So yes, if your angle is in *degrees*, you will need to use PI/180 to convert it to *radians*:

```
var vec = function(c,a,d){
  nx = c[0] + (Math.cos(a * (Math.PI/180))*d)
  ny = c[1] + (Math.sin(a * (Math.PI/180))*d)
  return [nx,ny]
}

console.log(vec([10,10],45,50))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help James!